# Coturn behind NAT is unreachable in a TURN configuration

Tags: webrtc, kurento, stun, turn, coturn

I'm trying to install a [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) in a server that is behind a NAT, so I followed the instruction given by [Kurento's documentation](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html) to make it accessible behind the NAT.

The problem is that when I test it with [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) I have a "Not reachable?" result (see image below)

Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated.

Image :
[image: coturn bug ilustrated with ICE echanges]

thank you

Comment: What is your server's IP address?  I can test it out to see if it's reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your config.
I would try to use another port (i.e. 80 or 443) and make sure your credentials are correct.